# Accessing registered services from MVVM Cross IoC Container

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, ioc-container

I'm using MVVM Cross in a project that uses multiple services.  What I would like to do is to retrieve, from the IoC container a list of currently registered services.  For example:

```
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IService1, IService1>();
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IService2, IService2>();
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IService3, IService3>();
```

Then

```
var s1 = Mvx.Resolve<IService1>();
var s3 = Mvx.Resolve<IService3>();
```

So now I want to return a list of active services.  I know that I can do this using reflection, but I wanted to know if there was a way to get this from the IoC container instead; something like:

```
var activeSvc = Mvx.GetAllServices();
```

Is this possible?  In `MvxSimpleIoCContainer` there is a dictionary of resolvers:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, IResolver> _resolvers = new Dictionary<Type, IResolver>();
```

This looks to be what I want, but it isn't publicly exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - this functionality isn't currently supported by the interface (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/IMvxIoCProvider.cs) or the "simple" implementation (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs)

If you feel this is functionality that would be commonly needed, then you could send a feature request (or pull request!)

But it might be easiest to start by implementing your own IoC container (based on that source) that exposes the exact functionality your platform needs.

---

Alternatively, you could use some reflection within your own assemblies to identify the exact services/interfaces you are looking for (it feels like your app won't actually want the list of all Types registered with IoC, but rather just a specific set that live somewhere in one particular part of your app)

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Yes, I did consider reflection, but it can be costly.

Comment: My suggestion: prototype using reflection - if it costs too much, then you can optimize. (Same goes for using IoC and MvvmCross)